# Scribe OAuth not working on android, error 500

Tags: android, oauth, scribe

I am using the below code to access a Magento api. I have used scribe to complete the Oauth process in which i am using fixed access token so I bypassed few steps of OAuth. Below program works fine when executing as java project but when I am trying it with android it always respond with error 500, service temporary unavailable.
I have included CommonsCodec in both project to have similar encoding.
during debug i am getting every thing same except response.

Please suggest what am I missing or, how alternate way to accomplish the same.

```
package org.scribe.examples;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest;
import org.scribe.model.Response;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.model.Verb;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;

/**
 * Example test driver for the Magento17Api class - 
 * Magento Community 1.7.x and Enterprise 1.12 support REST APIs going forward
 * 
 * @see  http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/the-magento-rest-api-a-better-way-to-integrate-business-applications/
 * @author Mike Salera
 */
public class MagentoExample
{
    public static final String MAGENTO_API_KEY = "MY key";
    public static final String MAGENTO_API_SECRET = "my secret";
    public static final String MAGENTO_REST_API_URL = "http://000.000.0.00/api/rest";

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                                    .provider(MagentoAuth.class)
                                    .apiKey(MAGENTO_API_KEY)
                                    .apiSecret(MAGENTO_API_SECRET)
                                    .debug()
                                    .build();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("=== Mage v1.7.0.2 OAuth Workflow ===");
        System.out.println();

//      // Obtain the Request Token
//      System.out.println("Fetching the Request Token...");
//      Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
//      System.out.println("Got the Request Token!");
//      System.out.println();
//
//      System.out.println("Now go and authorize Scribe here:");
//      System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));
//      System.out.println("And paste the verifier here");
//      System.out.print(">>");
//      Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
//      System.out.println();
//
//      // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
//      System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
//      Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
        Token accessToken=new Token("hard coded access token", "hard coded secret");
        System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
        System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken + " )");
        System.out.println();

        // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
        System.out.println("Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, MAGENTO_REST_API_URL + "/customers");
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();
        System.out.println("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(response.getBody());

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Thats it man! Go and build something awesome with Scribe! :)");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scribe is not meant to be used in android as per my research on scribe current library. Finally i got it working by using [oauth-signpost library](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) it's working without any problem and its easy to integrate.

all you need to do is to include signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar and signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar

```
 public OAuthConsumer getOauthConsumer() {
    OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(COUNSUMER_KEY, COUNSUMER_SECRET);
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
    return consumer;
}
```

This will provide you OAuthConsumer that can be used to sign request

```
HttpPost request=new HttpPost(completeURL);
        getOauthConsumer().sign(request)
```

that's it you are done. Happy coding :)

Comment: @RQube I am unable to get JSON from Magento REST API using above code. How to get that?

Comment: @OsamaMohammedShaikh I have moved to other project so can't share the code. Post your code in a new question and ping me url then i'll try to find a solution for you.